# Output of JAVA_HOME into variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to capture $JAVA_HOME into a variable

I tried this:

```
output = $(echo $JAVA_HOME)
echo $output
```

I also tried :

```
output = $($JAVA_HOME)
echo $output
```

and the result for both is:
`output: not found`

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear to my why do you want to assign value of one variable to another variable but you need to remove whitespaces around `=`, it should be:

```
output=$(echo $JAVA_HOME)
```

or even better and easier:

```
output="$JAVA_HOME"
```